# What is Brasilia time zone name?

Tags: time, timezone, clock

For Buenos Aires, Argentina, time zone name is `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires`.

For Toronto, Canada, time zone name is `America/Toronto`.

For Brasilia, Brazil, time zone name is `???`

I have checked the tz database and there is no record for Brasilia. Does anybody know it?

Comment: When I look at http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc there's a popup list of all kinds of time zones, including "`America/Sao_Paulo`".  I don't see a "`Brasilia`" listed there.  I do see there is such a thing as ["Brasilia Standard/Summer Time"](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/south-america/brazil/brazilian-states/distrito-federal/) however [out of the three time zones in Brazil](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/south-america/brazil/time-brazil/)

Comment: America/Sao_Paulo seems to be the right one, thanks

Answer (score 4):

It cost me a lot of headaches but I have found it, is the same as Sao_Paulo, `America/Sao_Paulo`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it is `America/Sao_Paulo`.

Wikipedia is a great reference for this sort of thing. See the following articles:

- [List of TZ Database Time Zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
- [Time in Brazil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil)
- [Brasília](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bras%C3%ADlia)

You can also look in [the actual TZDB sources](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/bd3e920d0e20e1ecbcfa19caa227ec18acf3c900/southamerica#L1089-1095) and see that `America/Sao_Paulo` includes "Distrito Federal (DF)".  Wikipedia told us that Brasília is indeed in the federal district.